# How do I take dropdown content to the front using z-index?

Tags: html, css, dropdown, z-index, devtools

A dropdown div element which is supposed to work [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoTCl.png) in mobile view is appearing like this mobile view [In inspect Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LjP1.png).

I tried to change CSS z-index stylings of almost all related nav elements and left this one at "z-index:121212 !important;" and still the dropdown div is appearing behind all the other nav links.

Does anyone know why this is happening? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my HTML code and it's CSS:

```css
  .navbar-mobile .dropdown>.dropdown-active {
    display: block;
    z-index: 121212;
  }
  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: var(--bg-dark);
    min-width: 200px;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 101000;
    animation: marketNav 0.5s;
  }
  .dropdown-content a {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
  }      
  .dropdown-content a:hover{
    background-color: var(--main-color);
    color: #000 !important;
  }      
  .dropdown-content a:hover{
    color: #1F586B;
  }
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content{
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .nav-pills.has-two .nav-item .nav-link.active {
    background-color: var(--main-color);
    color: #000;
  }
  .nav-link{
    font-weight: 600 !important;
    letter-spacing: 0.8px;
  }
  @media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {

    .support-link{
      margin-right: 10px!important;
    }
    .nav-link{
      padding-left: 25px!important;
    }
  }
  .nav-pills.has-two .nav-item .nav-link {
    background-color: #000 !important;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    -ms-border-radius: 0;
    -o-border-radius: 0;
    padding: 12px 20px;
  }
```

```html
<!-- Navigation -->
    <header id="header" class="fixed-top ">
        <div class="container d-flex align-items-center justify-content-lg-between">
            <div class="logo me-auto me-lg-0">
                <a href="index.htm">

                    <span>
                        <img class="img-fluid rounded sm-device-img text-align" src="asset/theme1/images/logo/logo.svg" width="100%" alt="pp">                    
                    </span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <nav id="navbar" class="navbar order-last order-lg-0">
                <ul>
                    <li class="active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="index.htm">Home</a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <a class="dropbtn nav-link">Market</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-content">

                                <a href="">Forex</a>
                                <a href="">Cryptocurrencies</a>
                                <a href="">Indices</a>
                                <a href="">Stocks</a>
                                <a href="">Commodities</a>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mobile-view marketNav">
                            <a href="">Forex</a>
                            <a href="">Cryptocurrencies</a>
                            <a href="">Indices</a>
                            <a href="">Stocks</a>
                            <a href="">Commodities</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <a class="dropbtn nav-link">Trading</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-content">

                                <a href="">Trading Platforms</a>
                                <a href="">Tools</a>
                                <a href="">Education</a>
                                <a href="">benefits</a>
    
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mobile-view marketNav">

                            <a class="sub-nav-link" href="">Trading Platforms</a>
                            <a class="sub-nav-link" href="">Tools</a>
                            <a class="sub-nav-link" href="">Education</a>
                            <a class="sub-nav-link" href="">benefits</a>

                        </div>
                    </li>
    
                    <li>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="">Account Types</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="d-md-block d-lg-none d-block ">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="">Login</a>
                        <a class="btn-border-inverse col-12 btn-sm me-3" href="">Register</a>
                    </li>
                    
                </ul>
                <i class="bi bi-list mobile-nav-toggle"></i>
            </nav>
            <div class="header-right d-flex d-none  d-md-none d-lg-block">
                <a href="" class="btn-border btn-sm me-3">Login</a>
                <a href="" class="btn-border-inverse btn-sm me-3">Register</a>


            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
<!-- Navigation Ends -->
```

**Edit:** I found a way to solve this issue. The links weren't able to be clicked when they are behind the main "nav-links". So I added blank divs with heights to appear below the nav-link where the dropdown-content would appear with the help of some JS and CSS to make it hidden in larger screens. Now I am able to click the links in the "dropdown-content".

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not with the z-index, but with the background-color. It is transparent, so it seems like it's behind the other text. You should set the variables you use in your code:

```
:root {
  --bg-dark: #000;
  --main-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion. Yet the problem remains unsolved. My problem is that I can't click on the links appearing in the dropdown menu. Instead the nav-links before/after the dropdown menu is being clicked. Referring with my screenshot above, when I click "Commodities", the nav-link "Login" is being clicked.

Comment: @TeeBeeU If you put links in the empty href attributes in your code they should work fine. I can try to find the problem if you send me a link to the code in the screenshot.

Comment: adding links to the href attribute doesn't solve it as well. I have tried it before. But and I managed to solve the issue. I'll edit my post with it. Your contribution is appreciated.